# Unable to update tkinter object grid column property whilst in recursion (Only updates if is recursion complete)

Tags: python, tkinter, recursion, grid

I am sorry if this is a dumb question, I am creating a basic game where I have used a 4 x4 grid layout using Tkinter labels. It will include 2 classes a Cat and a Dog. I have used relevant images for the animals and positioned them on the grid. There is also a button when the button is clicked it runs the walk function within the dog class. But the walk function is a recursion in which the grid location for the column changes but it does not change without the recursion ending. Is there an alternative to this or am I looking at this all wrong? Once again I am sorry if this is a stupid question but any support will be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *  # Importing Everything from Tkinter.
import random



class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name, age, colour):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.colour = colour

        if self.colour == "black":
            cat_image = PhotoImage(file="black_cat.png")
            self.image = cat_image

        if self.colour == "green":
            cat_image = PhotoImage(file="green_cat.png")
            self.image = cat_image


class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age, colour):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.colour = colour

        if self.colour == "black":
            dog_image = PhotoImage(file="black_dog.png")
            self.image = dog_image

        if self.colour == "green":
            dog_image = PhotoImage(file="green_dog.png")
            self.image = dog_image

    def walk(self):

        self.dog_current = opponent_image_label.grid_info()
        dog_current = self.dog_current["column"]
        print(dog_current)

        if dog_current >= 0 and dog_current < 3:
            dog_current = dog_current + 1
            opponent_image_label.grid(row=5, column=dog_current)
            mainwindow.after(100)
            self.walk()


        else:
            self.dog_current = 0
            dog_current = self.dog_current
            opponent_image_label.grid(row=5, column=dog_current)
            mainwindow.after(100)
            self.walk()




########################################################################################################################

########################################################################################################################

mainwindow = Tk()

tiles_bg = PhotoImage(file="tiles.png")  # This sets an image to a variable.

frame1 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame1.grid(row=2, column=0)

gridlabel_1 = Label(frame1, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_1.grid(row=2, column=0)

frame2 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame2.grid(row=2, column=1)

gridlabel_2 = Label(frame2, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_2.grid(row=2, column=1)

frame3 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame3.grid(row=2, column=2)

gridlabel_3 = Label(frame3, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_3.grid(row=2, column=2)

frame4 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame4.grid(row=2, column=3)

gridlabel_4 = Label(frame4, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_4.grid(row=2, column=3)

frame5 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame5.grid(row=3, column=0)

gridlabel_5 = Label(frame5, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_5.grid(row=3, column=0)

frame6 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame6.grid(row=3, column=1)

gridlabel_6 = Label(frame6, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_6.grid(row=3, column=1)

frame7 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame7.grid(row=3, column=2)

gridlabel_7 = Label(frame7, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_7.grid(row=3, column=2)

frame8 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame8.grid(row=3, column=3)

gridlabel_8 = Label(frame8, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_8.grid(row=3, column=3)

frame9 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame9.grid(row=4, column=0)

gridlabel_9 = Label(frame9, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_9.grid(row=4, column=0)

frame10 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame10.grid(row=4, column=1)

gridlabel_10 = Label(frame10, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_10.grid(row=4, column=1)

frame11 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame11.grid(row=4, column=2)

gridlabel_11 = Label(frame11, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_11.grid(row=4, column=2)

frame12 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame12.grid(row=4, column=3)

gridlabel_12 = Label(frame12, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_12.grid(row=4, column=3)

frame13 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame13.grid(row=5, column=0)

gridlabel_13 = Label(frame13, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_13.grid(row=5, column=0)

frame14 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame14.grid(row=5, column=1)

gridlabel_14 = Label(frame14, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_14.grid(row=5, column=1)

frame15 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame15.grid(row=5, column=2)

gridlabel_15 = Label(frame15, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_15.grid(row=5, column=2)

frame16 = Frame(mainwindow, bg="White", borderwidth=0, relief=RIDGE)
frame16.grid(row=5, column=3)

gridlabel_16 = Label(frame16, image=tiles_bg)
gridlabel_16.grid(row=5, column=3)

frame_button = Button(mainwindow, text="Play!", bg="purple", command=lambda: opponent.walk())
frame_button.config(font=("Ariel", 11, "bold"))
frame_button.grid(row=6, column=2)

########################################################################################################################


########################################################################################################################


r_int = random.randint(1, 2)

if r_int == 1:
    player_name = "Crazy Cat"

if r_int == 2:
    player_name = "Sleepy Cat"

r_int = random.randint(1, 2)

if r_int == 1:
    player_colour = "black"

if r_int == 2:
    player_colour = "green"

player_age = random.randint(1, 15)

player = Cat(player_name, player_age, player_colour)
player_image = player.image
player_image_label = Label(mainwindow, image=player_image)

player_image_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

r_int = random.randint(1, 2)

if r_int == 1:
    opponent_name = "Crazy Dog"

if r_int == 2:
    opponent_name = "Sleepy Dog"

r_int = random.randint(1, 2)

if r_int == 1:
    opponent_colour = "black"

if r_int == 2:
    opponent_colour = "green"

opponent_age = random.randint(1, 15)

opponent = Dog(opponent_name, opponent_age, opponent_colour)
opponent_image = opponent.image
opponent_image_label = Label(mainwindow, image=opponent_image)

opponent_image_label.grid(row=5, column=0)

mainwindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry if this isn't what you are asking but, the window will only update once the process is complete. For instance if you `time.sleep(10)` before adding a label, the window will freeze for 10 seconds. The only way around this is through the use of threads.

Comment: Thanks that does make sense, I have discovered an alternative, I will just use a canvas which will be a lot easier.